# Bootstrap multi column layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to build a layout same as below using bootstarp.

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-64 col-lg-42">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= asset_path( 'Thunderbolt-Display_3-5.jpg' ) %>">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-64 col-lg-22">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-64">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= asset_path( 'Thunderbolt-Display_3-5.jpg' ) %>">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-64 child-of-prmo-p2">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= asset_path( 'Thunderbolt-Display_3-5.jpg' ) %>">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Description:

The first big image will take 42 column on lg device and second will take 22 column. I achieve the same layout but my problem is to put the space in-between images as per design. I put the spacing as well but while resizing its not working proper.

The images which is being used is 5:3 aspect ration.

Comment: can you share the link ?

Comment: From the bootstrap site, "Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases" ... I'm not sure what you're trying to do with so many columns. As for the white space why not just do .left-image {padding-left: 10px}

Comment: I have extended the columns till upto 64.

Comment: You can use `col-lg-21 col-lg-offset-1` for adding the margin and additional `col-md-21 col-md-offset-1` for scaling

Comment: Here is the demo link https://jsfiddle.net/saorabh/nnsu8t35/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Use less columns in your `div`s, and try using one or two columns for the space between.

Comment: Here is the js fiddle which i have created https://jsfiddle.net/saorabh/nnsu8t35/1/embedded/result/